# Pass argument to lodash.throttle's callback

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to pass `component` to `someFuc` but when I run `someFuc`, its argument is an event. What am I doing wrong?

`window.addEventListener("resize", throttle(someFuc, 66, {'trailing': false}, component), false);`

Answer (score 2):

`_.throttle` doesn't actually take four arguments. Only three. So your component is being ignored. If you want to pass it in as the argument to `someFuc`, you could use lodash's `_.partial` function, or use an anonymous function. Here is code for both:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", _.throttle(_.partial(someFuc, component), 66, {trailing: false}), false);
```

OR

```
window.addEventListener("resize", _.throttle(() => sumeFuc(component), 66, {trailing: false}), false)
```

Comment: So the docs are wrong? https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle
"The func is invoked with the last arguments provided to the throttled function."

Comment: "The func is invoked with the last arguments provided to the throttled function" means that the function which `throttle` creates is invoked with the last set of arguments it has recieved. Ie, if you call the throttled function twice in a short time, the underlying function will be called only once with the arguments from the second call (the last one in this example).

Comment: I should also add that since you've set `trailing: false`, that probably doesn't apply anyway, since the underlying function will be invoked on the leading edge of a group of calls (so will actually receive arguments from its first caller).